# Dart `build_config` rename `buildStep.inputId` file

Tags: dart, dart-build

I want to rename (not just the extension) a file in my `Builder`. Is there any reason I shouldn't just create my own `File` based on `buildStep.inputId` and write to the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do this then lots of weird things will happen:

- It will cause a new build (the build system will think you just manually created a file)
- Dependencies get all weird - that file will now be available to be consumed by any other builder (even ones that ran before it). This could cause infinite loops or other weirdness.
- Your builder won't be portable to bazel or other build system integrations outside of build_runner
- We may in the future block you from doing this entirely

Basically, you would be circumventing the whole build system, and the behavior becomes undefined.